# Does WriteFile signal the event if it completes synchronously

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Does the [WriteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx) function signal the event passed in via the `lpOverlapped` parameter if it completes synchronously and succeeds? Does it signal the event if it fails synchronously? I have opened the handle to a file with the `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag. I wasn't to able to figure this out from the documentation and couldn't repro this case easily in code.

Comment: if operation complete synchronously and succeeds event will be set. if operation complete synchronously and fail system not set event. anyway - you need use/check event state only if operation return `ERROR_IO_PENDING` - in this case when operation complete (with any final status) event will be set. if operation complete synchronous - you not need event state at all. assume that it in undefined state

Comment: 'I wasn't to able to figure this out from the documentation' yeah, me neither, one reason why I have avoided that hEvent mechanism and gone with a completion routine or 'real' IOCP.    If you are stuck with waiting on some hEvent synchro, however, can you not just dodge the issue by explicitly signaling the object if the call completes synchronously so that whatever thread is waiting runs on anyway?

Comment: not direct this documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365538(v=vs.85).aspx) - look `FILE_SKIP_SET_EVENT_ON_HANDLE` section - the explicit event signaled when and only when request returns with a success code, or the error returned is ERROR_PENDING

Comment: @Martin, the event is unfortunately an auto reset event, so I cannot explicitly signal the object as that would give two signals to the caller.

Comment: @tcb - the auto reset event is (double) bad choice here. if use events - use manual reset event better. system reset it, before pass request to driver. *WriteFile resets the event specified by the hEvent member of the OVERLAPPED structure to a nonsignaled state when it begins the I/O operation. Therefore, there is no need for the caller to do so.* - but if you pass invalid arguments to `WriteFile` - it not reset your event - return before this point. and use apc or iocp completion better choice. iocp with `FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS` (vista +) - the best choice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all this question related not only to `WriteFile` but to any asynchronous I/O function - almost all functions which get pointer to an [`OVERLAPPED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342(v=vs.85).aspx) structure. because for all this functions `IRP` (*I/O request packet*) (look it definition in *wdm.h*) is allocated. `hEvent` handle from [`OVERLAPPED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684342(v=vs.85).aspx) converted to object pointer and stored in `PKEVENT UserEvent;` member of `IRP`. the event is set (or not set) exactly when `IRP` is completed in `IopCompleteRequest` routine. the `IRP` completion function is common for all I/O api, so and rules (when completion fire) is related to all. unfortunately this is very bad documented. the win32 layer (compare NT layer) added additional ,very thin, issues here.

based on [wrk src code](https://github.com/Zer0Mem0ry/ntoskrnl/blob/master/Io/iomgr/internal.c#L1292), we can see that  I/O Manager fire completion (was 3 types - event, apc and iocp (mutually exclusive)) for asynchronous io when
`!NT_ERROR( irp->IoStatus.Status )` or `irp->PendingReturned`.

if we use native api, which direct return `NTSTATUS` - when `(ULONG)status < 0xc0000000`. but here was very problematic range `0x80000000 <= status < 0xc0000000` or `NT_WARNING(status)` when unclear - are completion (even set, apc or packet to iocp queue) will be set. this is because before allocate `IRP` I/O Manager do some basic checks and can return error from here. usually  I/O Manager return errors from `NT_ERROR(status)` , which correct mean that will be no completion (event will be not set)), but exist and rarely exceptions. for example for [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx) (or `ZwNotifyChangeDirectoryFile`) the *lpBuffer* pointer must be DWORD-aligned (aligned exactly as [`FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364391(v=vs.85).aspx)) otherwise  I/O Manager return `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT` (0x80000002) from `NT_WARNING` range. but will be no completion (event set) in this case, because function fail **before** allocate `IRP`. from another case, if we call [`FSCTL_FILESYSTEM_GET_STATISTICS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364565(v=vs.85).aspx) with not large enough buffer - file system driver (not  I/O Manager ) return `STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW` (0x80000005). but because at this point `IRP` already allocated and code not from `NT_ERROR` range - will be event set.

so if error from  I/O Manager (before `IRP` allocated) - will be no completion. otherwise if error from driver (to which passed `IRP`) completion will be if function return `!NT_ERROR(status)`. as result if we get:

- `NT_SUCCESS(status)` (the `STATUS_PENDING` (`0x103`) is part of this) - will
  be
     completion
- `NT_ERROR(status)` will be no completion
- `NT_WARNING(status)` - unclear, depend this error from  I/O Manager
  (no) or driver(yes)

but with win32 layer make situation more worse. because unclear how it interpret `NT_WARNING(status)` - most win32 api interpret this as error - return *false* and set last error (converted from status). but some api - for example [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx) interpret this as **success** code - return *true* and not set last error. as result if we call [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx) with bad aligned buffer (but valid other parameters) - it return.. **true** and not set any error. but api call is really fail. the `ZwNotifyChangeDirectoryFile` internal return `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT` here.

from another side, if `DeviceIoControl` for `FSCTL_FILESYSTEM_GET_STATISTICS` fail (return false) with code `ERROR_MORE_DATA` (converted from `STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW`) event(completion) will be set in this case.

also by win32 error code we can not understand - are initial status was `NT_ERROR` or `NT_WARNING` code - conversion ([`RtlNtStatusToDosError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680600(v=vs.85).aspx)) status to win32 error lost this info

problem with `NT_WARNING(status)` range, begin from vista, can be resolved if we use IOCP completion (instead event) and set [`FILE_SKIP_COMPLETION_PORT_ON_SUCCESS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365538(v=vs.85).aspx) on file - in this case I/O manager queue a completion entry to the port, when and only when `STATUS_PENDING` will be returned by native api call. for win32 layer this usually mean that api return false and last error is `ERROR_IO_PENDING`. exceptions - `WriteFileEx`, `ReadFileEx` which return true here. however this not help in case `ReadDirectoryChangesW` anyway (I assume that this is windows bug)

also read [`FILE_SKIP_SET_EVENT_ON_HANDLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365538(v=vs.85).aspx) section - this implicitly say when explicit event (from overlapped) set in case asynchronous function - when request returns with a **success code**, or the error returned is `ERROR_IO_PENDING`. but here question - what is **success code** ? true returned by win32 api ? not always, as visible from `FSCTL_FILESYSTEM_GET_STATISTICS` - the `ERROR_MORE_DATA` (`STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW`) also success code. or `STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES` returned by [`NtQueryDirectoryFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntquerydirectoryfile) also success code - event (apc or iocp completion) will be set. but same [`NtQueryDirectoryFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntquerydirectoryfile) can return `STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT`, when `FileInformation` bad aligned - this is fail code, because returned from I/O Manager before allocate `IRP`

the `NT_WARNING` status in most case is success code (will be completion), but win32 layer in most case interpret it as fail code (return false).

code example for tests:

```
ULONG BOOL_TO_ERROR(BOOL fOk)
{
    return fOk ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
}

void CheckEventState(HANDLE hEvent, ULONG err, NTSTATUS status = RtlGetLastNtStatus())
{
    DbgPrint("error = %u(%x)", err, err ? status : STATUS_SUCCESS);

    switch (WaitForSingleObject(hEvent, 0))
    {
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        DbgPrint("Signaled\n");
        break;
    case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        DbgPrint("NON signaled\n");
        break;
    default:
        DbgPrint("error=%u\n", GetLastError());
    }
#if 1
    EVENT_BASIC_INFORMATION ebi;
    if (0 <= ZwQueryEvent(hEvent, EventBasicInformation, &ebi, sizeof(ebi), 0))
    {
        DbgPrint("EventState = %x\n", ebi.EventState);
    }
#endif
}

void demoIoEvent()
{
    WCHAR sz[MAX_PATH];
    GetSystemDirectoryW(sz, RTL_NUMBER_OF(sz));

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(sz, 0, FILE_SHARE_VALID_FLAGS, 0, 
        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED|FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, 0);

    if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        FILESYSTEM_STATISTICS fs;

        OVERLAPPED ov = {};

        if (ov.hEvent = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0))
        {
            FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION fni;
            IO_STATUS_BLOCK iosb;

            // STATUS_DATATYPE_MISALIGNMENT from I/O manager
            // event will be not set
            NTSTATUS status = ZwNotifyChangeDirectoryFile(hFile, ov.hEvent, 0, 0, &iosb, 
                (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*)(1 + (PBYTE)&fni), 1, FILE_NOTIFY_VALID_MASK, FALSE);

            CheckEventState(ov.hEvent, ERROR_NOACCESS, status);

            // windows bug ! ReadDirectoryChangesW return .. true and no last error
            // but really api fail. event will be not set and no notifications
            ULONG err = BOOL_TO_ERROR(ReadDirectoryChangesW(hFile,
                (FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*)(1 + (PBYTE)&fni), 1, 0, FILE_NOTIFY_VALID_MASK, 0, &ov, 0));

            CheckEventState(ov.hEvent, err);

            // fail with ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER (STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL)
            // NT_ERROR(c0000023) - event will be not set
            err = BOOL_TO_ERROR(DeviceIoControl(hFile, 
                FSCTL_FILESYSTEM_GET_STATISTICS, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &ov));

            CheckEventState(ov.hEvent, err);

            // ERROR_MORE_DATA (STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
            // !NT_ERROR(80000005) - event will be set
            // note - win 32 api return false and error != ERROR_IO_PENDING
            err = BOOL_TO_ERROR(DeviceIoControl(hFile, 
                FSCTL_FILESYSTEM_GET_STATISTICS, 0, 0, &fs, sizeof(fs), 0, &ov));

            CheckEventState(ov.hEvent, err);

            if (err == ERROR_MORE_DATA)
            {
                SYSTEM_INFO si;
                GetSystemInfo(&si);

                ULONG cb = si.dwNumberOfProcessors * fs.SizeOfCompleteStructure;

                union {
                    PVOID pv;
                    PBYTE pb;
                    PFILESYSTEM_STATISTICS pfs;
                };

                pv = alloca(cb);

                // must be NOERROR(0) here
                // !NT_ERROR(0) - event will be set
                err = BOOL_TO_ERROR(DeviceIoControl(hFile, FSCTL_FILESYSTEM_GET_STATISTICS, 0, 0, 
                    pv, cb, 0, &ov));

                CheckEventState(ov.hEvent, err);

                if (!err && GetOverlappedResult(hFile, &ov, &cb, FALSE))
                {
                    do 
                    {
                        // use pfs here
                    } while (pb += fs.SizeOfCompleteStructure, --si.dwNumberOfProcessors);
                }
            }

            CloseHandle(ov.hEvent);
        }
        CloseHandle(hFile);
    }
}
```

and output:

```
error = 998(80000002)NON signaled
EventState = 0
error = 0(0)NON signaled
EventState = 0
error = 122(c0000023)NON signaled
EventState = 0
error = 234(80000005)Signaled
EventState = 1
error = 0(0)Signaled
EventState = 1
```

Comment: Well, I don't really know how to put this...  I have been developing multithreaded, networked user apps on Windows for decades and this answer is the most impressive explanation of an I/O interaction I have ever seen on SO. If I could upvote it 10 times, I would do so.  Many thanks, (still won't be using that nasty hEvent signaling, though:).

Comment: @MartinJames - yes, i also never use event completion in self code, because he have no additional context parameter, unlike apc or iocp completion. i primary use iocp too. however all this related to all completion types - events, apc, iocp

Comment: With an APC completion routine, I have used the hEvent field to store a context object pointer or, at least on 32-bit I have.  Not sure if that field is wide enough for a pointer on 64-bit, (so IOCP).

Comment: @MartinJames: `hEvent` this is `HANDLE` - pointer size - wide enough for store context. however in case apc or iocp - we can use `OVERLAPPED` pointer returned in completion (or from iocp) as context. if we use native api we have and separate context pointer too

Comment: @MartinJames so from my look always better use pointer to `OVERLAPPED` (`IO_STATUS_BLOCK`) as operation context - anyway it must be unique and live until io complete. the NT api let for as use separate context pointer (!= pointer to `IO_STATUS_BLOCK`) but here we almost nothing gain - enough and `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` as context. if you develop/interesting asynchronous (networked and any io) code in windows - [this](https://github.com/rbmm/LIB/tree/master/ASIO) how i prefer use this

Comment: ' it must be unique and live until io complete' - yup, I put the OVERLAPPED block in as a struct field of the context object:).  Many thanks for all the info!

Comment: @MartinJames - *I put the OVERLAPPED block in as a struct field of the context object* - yes, i too. with different that i *inherit* context object from `OVERLAPPED` and use `static_cast` for get context back from `OVERLAPPED` pointer